# Codeigniter Ionauth generating wrong email in forgot password

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth

When I click forget password, the link in the email is:

`http://10.50.2.124/ticket/auth/res=t_password/CHkp7v2VAxXe09IJx060refc9881e6bb20ab2013`
insted of

```
http://10.50.2.124/ticket/auth/reset_password/CHkp7v2VAxXe09IJx060refc9881e6bb20ab2013
```

The setting in ion_auth.php is:

```
$config['use_ci_email'] = TRUE; 
$config['email_config'] = array(
                        'mailtype' => 'html',
                         );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try set `crlf` to fix the issue:

```
$this->email->set_crlf("\r\n");
```

or

```
$config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
```